# Lost files with gulp-clean

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I just started work with gulp and not completely understand some things.
Here is my gulpfile

```
gulp.task('css', function(){
  var processors = [
    csswring({
      removeAllComments: true
    })
  ];

  gulp.src(['css/**/*.css', '!css/reset.css'])
    .pipe(concat('withoutReset.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp'));

  return gulp.src(['css/reset.css', 'tmp/withoutReset.css'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('/map/style'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'));
});

gulp.task('main', ['css'], function() {
  return gulp.src('tmp', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('default', ['main']);
```

When I run this task in public/css/style.css I get just minify reset file without all other, but if I commented clean line, it's works fine.

I thought style.css should created before run clean task, that's not true?

How can I make it works fine without changing folder structure, that's means reset file can be on same level with some other which also should follow after it(lines from reset should be always first)

And it will be nice if you explain or send link where I can read why it doesn't work with current code

Comment: Second `gulp.src` in css task doesn't wait for first `gulp.src` to finish. What is the reason for writing tmp files there?

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me!(

Thank to @Heikki - it was problem with asynchronously, so I put concatenation to separate task(guess exist someway to made it in one task, but I just beginner) and it works well)

Comment: To make it in one task `.pipe` the two pipelines together without desting into 'tmp'. That is the whole point of gulp/pipelines. No need for temporary stuff.